# Differenze di uso tra "linea" e "riga"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Non capisco molto bene quali siano le differenze di uso tra queste due parole, "linea" e "riga". Potreste dirmi qualcosa al riguardo?

Comment: Per curiosità, come funzionano le parole analoghe – se ce ne sono – in catalano e in castigliano?

Comment: In catalano, ci sono le parole "línia" e "ratlla", e in castigliano abbiamo "línea" e "raya". Ma penso che abbiano usi un po' diversi dall'italiano (questa è la ragione della mia domanda). Per esempio, si può dire "un escrit de quatre línies" o "[las rayas de la mano](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00F9XJR2K/ref=redir_mdp_mobile/192-8293623-5470142)".

Comment: Altri usi di questi vocaboli sono analoghi a quelli delle parole "linea" e "riga".

Comment: La domanda riguarda un ambito specifico (ad esempio, l'ambito grafico) oppure queste due parole in generale?

Comment: Riguarda queste due parole in generale, @Lucia. Come ho già detto, ho osservato che gli usi di "linea" e "riga" sono un po' diversi da quelli delle parole analoghe in catalano e in castigliano e perciò ho fatto questa domanda.

Comment: Grazie delle spiegazioni, e mi scuso se la mia richiesta era fuori tema. È interessante che rispetto agli esempi catalano e castigliano che fai, l'italiano si comporta all'opposto e parla in genere di “righe” per i testi scritti e di “linee” per la mano.

Comment: @DaG: è anche corretto "las líneas de la mano".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Linea** si usa in ambito geometrico, indica un segno grafico, generalmente sottile, tracciato da un punto a un altro su una superficie. Vale anche in ambito sportivo, le linee che delimitano il campo di gioco. Può indicare anche un profilo, le linee delle mani e molto altro.

**Riga** si usa principalmente per indicare una riga di testo, ovvero un insieme di parole su una stessa linea. Si usa anche per indicare una serie di persone o di cose allineate una a fianco dell'altra. Un altro uso comune è la "riga dei capelli".

Answer (score 2):

Oltre a ciò che @pinckerman ha già detto, ci sono alcune espressioni più o meno fisse:

> - (Ri)mettere in riga (riportare all'ordine una persona indisciplinata).
> - Leggere tra le righe (interpretare, trovare significati non espliciti).
> - Rompere le righe (soprattutto militare, disfare l'allineamento di un gruppo).
> - Sopra le righe (detto di qualcuno o qualcosa un po' esagerato o anticonformista).
> - A grandi linee (lo stesso che "a grandes rasgos").
> - Prima linea (militare, il punto più avanzato della battaglia, usato anche metaforicamente, per esempio, "un poliziotto in prima linea nella lotta alla criminalità").

Sicuramente ce ne sono molte altre.